# Can 'this.value' actually be used, successfully, in a function call from a trigger event?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

I give up!  From the W3C Web examples, "Beginning Web Programming with
HTML, XHTML, and CSS" by Jon Duckett, "DOM Scripting - Web Design with 
JavaScript and the Document Object Model - Second Edition" by Jeremy 
Keith and Jeffrey Sambells, "JavaScript, The Definitive Guide" by 
David Flanagan == ALL suggest, 'this.value' can be passed as an argument to a JavaScript function.

This is the trigger:

```
<td id="yearOfDraw">
  <select id="selectedYear" onchange="storeValue('y', this.value)">;
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select Year
    </option>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      yearOption();
    </script>
  </select>
</td>
```

...the above, as well as the following, I have tried without success;

storeValue() as a library function == the literal, "y", is passed but 
not this.value.

storeValue() in the head element == same results...

onchange options:

```
    onchange="storeValue('y', " + this.value)>;  // breaks the code.
    onchange="storeValue(this.value, 'y')">; // this.value is not passed.
    onchange="storeValue(this.value)">; // ...nothing is passed
    onchange="storeValue(alert('this.value is: ', this.value)">; //displays \
the value selected, just doesn't pass it to the function.
```

(From "stackoverflow-JavaScript pass argument this.value to function")

```
    onchange="storeValue('y', " + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)>; // breaks the code.
```

I don't see "scoping" as an issue since 'this' would be a pointer to 
the Element object, select, and thus, Global 'in scope' to the called
function. But this presumption doesn't explain the problem.  Equally,
how would one go about making, 'this.value', Global in scope?

Any ideas?

Thanks,
JungeBleu

Comment: Where are the *storeValue* and *yearOption* functions? Is *yearOption* even relevant?

Comment: What makes you think it is not passed? How is the `change` event triggered, via the UI?

Comment: *"Can 'this.value' actually be used, successfully, in a function call from a trigger event?"* Yes. However, it's not clear to me what the problem in your code is, since you didn't provide a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to comment but don't have enough rep. :)

Anyway, you seem to be populating the options via javascript. If that is the case, storeValue is not aware of the extra options populated in the DOM as  `yearOption()` only populates the DOM after the page is loaded.

However, if you were to have all the options in the in the 1st place or you bind `storeValue` after `yearOption()` populates the DOM, perhaps using an anonymous function, it might work.

**EDIT**

1. BTW, this is why we use libraries like `jquery` so that we can attach events later - after the DOM is loaded -  in a really simple way :)
2. Also, `onchange` won't trigger if you only have one option as you do in your example...

What does `yearOption()` do exactly? See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LsY3Y/1/

Comment: Where or when the function called by the select's change hander is declared is not relevant here. It is passed a value when the change event occurs, and presumably the options must exist in order to be selected and cause a change event to be dispatched.

Comment: Time for me to supply more in depth information: the browser is Mozilla Firefox v.28.0.  The 'yearOption()' function captures the current year, calculates the last ten years, and through a "for loop" uses DOM to fill in the list of '<option>' years within the current 'select' element.  I find it odd that 'alert' shows the selected value but 'this.value' can't be seen by 'storeValue'.

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly using IE 8 or lower (or some later version in quirks mode or compatability mode with version 8 or lower), where options with no value attribute <strike>do not return a value</strike> return an empty string, not the option's text. In other (W3C compliant) browsers, the text will be returned.

The following "works":

```
<script>
    // Simple function to report values
    function storeValue(s, v) {
      console.log(s + ':' + v);
    }

</script>

<select onchange="storeValue('y', this.value)">
  <option selected>Select Year
  <option value="2000">2000
  <option value="2000">2001
  <option>2002              <!-- Option without a value attribute -->
</select>
```

Regarding your other questions:

> I don't see "scoping" as an issue since 'this' would be a pointer to the Element object, select, and thus, Global 'in scope' to the called function.

*this* is only global in global code, it's always resolved in the current exeuction context. In global code it is the global object, in any other context it is set by how a function is called or by using [*bind*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5).

Inline event handler code is wrapped in a function and when that function is called, its *this* is set to the element. So even though the inline code appears to be global, it's actually function scoped and has it's own, local *this* that is not the global object.

> how would one go about making, 'this.value', Global in scope?

You can't, see above. :-)

Comment: By "*do not return a value*", you mean they act as if `value=""`?

Comment: The value property for form controls always returns a string, so even if the *value* attribute is missing, accessing it will return "" (empty string). In early IE the DOM [*hasAttribute*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-ElHasAttr) method was broken so it was very difficult to determine whether the attribute was set to "" or missing, making generic functions to get the value of a select element also difficult. But likely you knew that and were just prompting me to correct the answer. :-)